# Kendo grid checkbox Enable depends the value of the javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I make Kendo grid checkbox again Active if it is InActive when the value in the variable checkenabled =1

```
Columns.Bound(c=>c.IsChecked)
.ClientTemplate(
    "<label class=\"switch switch-green switch-md\">"+
    "<input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"switch-input\" onclick=\"setChecked(#ID #,'MyTest');\" #(IsActive) {#checked#} #/>"+
    "<span  class=\"switch-label\" data-on=\"Active\" data-off=\"Inactive\"></span>"+
    "<span class=\"switch-handle\"></span>"+
    "</label>"            
)

<scrit>
    function setChecked(ID,text){
        checkenabled = 1
    }
<script>
```